# Best project type for shutdown pc in idle

Tags: windows, service, shutdown

I want my pc to display a messagebox or something similar after 1hour. If the user doesn't click "dismiss" the pc should shutdown. This application should start automatically everytime I start my PC. It also shouldn't be visible (in the taskbar or somewhere else) that the application is running (just like a service).

I tried to accomplish this task with a windows service but there is no chance to display a message box. Is there a better project type to finish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You should create both a service and a desktop application,
The desktop application should signal the service whether to shutdown or not.

Comment: So the timer is running in the service and the desktop application only displays the message box and returns the result to the service?
But how do they communicate?

Comment: They can communicate using any kind of IPC, for example.. you can set the service to listen on port 12321 on localhost, waiting for the word "shutdown" to come, once the desktop application has decided, it will connect to localhost on port 12321 and send the data containing "shutdown" (You may want a better magic word), then the service will shutdown.